# How do I make a Font Preview?

Tags: font-design, microsoft-word

I have created a custom font using FontForge. I have exported it as an OpenType (OTF) and I have installed it by right clicking the exported files and selecting "Install"

However, when I go to select the Font, it shows me a 'preview' that doesn't look like the font at all.

Where is it getting this preview from?  How can I make it so that it shows a preview?

[image]

Comment: Look carefully at the names (PostScript name, etc.) and unique identifier of your font. There is probably a clash there.